# Searching for replacement keys for specific window lock

Tags: windows, lock, security

I have this window lock on two of the windows in my flat:

[image]

The key required for this is hexagonal, and it has a pin hole in the centre.

Here is the lock in context:

[image]

Does anyone recognise the lock, and know where I could buy replacement keys from?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a [security Allen wrench](https://www.google.com/search?q=security+Allen+wrench) (six-sided rod with a hole in the middle).

Comment: Bill, if the center hole is threaded then you're looking for a handle; not a key.   I think the locking mechanism is of the same design as an hex drive operator crank.  If one took the paint off the lock body there might be a manufacturer name imprinted in the metal.